# Cannot convert value of type Size3D? to excepted argument of type Size3D?

Tags: swift, xcode

I have weird error in Xcode, saying I cannot convert value of type Size3D? to excepted argument of type Size3D?. I have Size3D defined in only one place - different module, but it's imported and I can init Size3D. 
Error appears on the last line of this code:

```
let size3D: Size3D? = {
            guard let viewport = geometry["viewport"] as? [String : [String : Double]] else { return nil }
            guard let northeast = viewport["northeast"], let southwest = viewport["southwest"] else { return nil }
            guard let northeastLat = northeast["lat"], let northeastLng = northeast["lng"] else { return nil }
            guard let southwestLat = southwest["lat"], let southwestLng = southwest["lng"] else { return nil }
            let northeastECEF = ECEF(location: CLLocation(latitude: northeastLat, longitude: northeastLng))
            let southwestECEF = ECEF(location: CLLocation(latitude: southwestLat, longitude: southwestLng))
            let width  = abs(southwestECEF.x - northeastECEF.x)
            let depth  = abs(southwestECEF.y - northeastECEF.y)
            let size3D = Size3D(width: width, depth: depth, height: 3)
            // If size is too large return nil.
            return size3D.diagonal < 25 ? size3D : nil
        }()


WorldObjectLocation(location: CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: lon), size3D: size3D, ignoreAltitude: true, ignoreCourse: true)
```

which is defined in this class:

```
public class WorldObjectLocation: CLLocation {
    public let ignoreLocationAltitude: Bool
    public let ignoreLocationCourse:   Bool
    public let size3D:                 Size3D?

    public init(location: CLLocation, size3D: Size3D?, ignoreAltitude: Bool, ignoreCourse: Bool) {
        self.size3D            = size3D
        ignoreLocationAltitude = ignoreAltitude
        ignoreLocationCourse   = ignoreCourse
        super.init(coordinate: location.coordinate, altitude: location.altitude, horizontalAccuracy: location.horizontalAccuracy, verticalAccuracy: location.verticalAccuracy, course: location.course, speed: location.speed, timestamp: location.timestamp)
    }

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

and here is Size3D:

```
public struct Size3D {
    public let width:  Double
    public let depth:  Double
    public let height: Double
    public init(width: Double, depth: Double, height: Double) {
        self.width  = width
        self.depth  = depth
        self.height = height
    }
    public var diagonal: Double { return sqrt(width * width + depth * depth + height * height) }
}
```

What can this error be? How to fix this?

Comment: I needed to add some code you didn't post - fudging things for your variables lat, lon, and size3D... bottom line? It builds fine. Maybe the issue is elsewhere. Post your definitions for each of those variables.

Comment: Show how you instantiate the `size3D` that you put in `WorldObjectLocation(...)` as argument.

Comment: "Error appears here" Where?